# Dynamically created Partial View does not call controller action on submit

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, partial-views

I am using AJAX to replace bootstrap modal content with a partial view like this:

**Main View HTML**

```
   <div class="container row form-horizontal">
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content" id="myModalContent">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**AJAX script inside main view**

```
  $(function () {
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e) {
        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');
            bindForm(this);

            $("form").removeData("validator");
            $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");

        });



        return false;
    });
});

function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {
        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    alert('reloading');
                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

**Partial View HTML**

```
@model MVC_Replica.Models.Location

<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Add New Location</h3>
</div>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","Locations",FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="modal-body">

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationState, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LocationState, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationState, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <span id="progress" class="text-center" style="display: none;">
        <img src="~/media/ajax-loading.gif" alt="wiat" />
        Wait..
    </span>

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-left" value="Create" />
    <button class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

}

**Result**

The modal opens correctly and client side validation works perfectly well. However, when i `submit` the `partial view`, the following controller action is never executed:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Location location)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            location.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
            db.Locations.Add(location);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Json(new { success = true });
        }

        return PartialView("_CreateLocation", location);
    }
```

I tried placing a brake point next to `ModelState.IsValid` but it never gets hit.Also the browser console is not displaying any errors

**What could be the problem?**

**Edit**

I managed to get the partial view to call the create action controller by storing `anchor` `href` value in a `global variable` and changing the `bindForm` function:

```
 var actionUrl;
$(function () {

    $('form').submit(function () {

       // alert(this.action);
    });
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
    $(document).on('click', 'a[data-modal]', function (e) {
        actionUrl = this.href;

        $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {

            $('#myModal').modal({
                keyboard: true
            }, 'show');

            bindForm();

            $("form").removeData("validator");
            $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");

        });

        return false;
    });
});
function bindForm() {
    $('form').on('submit',function () {

        $('#progress').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: actionUrl,
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#progress').hide();

                    location.reload();
                } else {
                    $('#progress').hide();
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm();
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Comment: What *does* happen? Worst case scenario, the form should try to post traditionally, without AJAX, so the page should change to *something*. If your AJAX is working, then you must be getting some sort of response, even if it's just a 404 or 500. Look for the AJAX request in your browser's development console and inspect the response.

Comment: Hi Chris, a post back occurs and my Main View HttpGet action result is invoked

Comment: By default, an action accepts both GET and POST. That means your problem is two-fold: 1) the wrong URL is being posted to and 2) the form is posting traditionally, rather than via AJAX. For the first, you'll need to inspect your routing and see what's up there. For the second, you probably need to use a delegate as likely the JavaScript code is not being applied to the new form code once it's replaced.

Comment: I have noticed that the bindForm function is not being executed. I have tried using the "on" delegate instead of the bindFunction().sumbit and i am getting the same results. However, as soon as i remove the dialog selector in the bidnForm function, it executes AJAX call correctly, but calls the Index Action Result instead of the required Create Action. So i guess i have an extra clue to work this out. Any ideas?

Comment: By delegate, I mean you need to bind to a parent element of the form that is never replaced, and have it "delegate" to the form via a selector. For example, something like `$('#myModalContent').on('submit', 'form', function () { /* do something * });`. In other words, you're binding to this div that doesn't change and having it delegate any submit events to whatever form element it finds when the event occurs.

Comment: Hi @ChrisPratt, i tried using the delegate as you suggested but with no success, the delegate function is never called, and i am back to square one. However, if i set a global variable and save anchor href value in it, and use it as a ajax url in the bindForm function, i get the required results. I added an edit. However, not sure if this is an elegant solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why the `create controller action` was never invoked, was because the `submit` event of the `bindForm` function was never being executed. As i have discovered, the `dialog` `selector` in the `bindForm` function stopped the event from being triggered. I have added an edit to the question explaining a possible solution.